# list using rows values from nth column till end of line

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy

I have comma seperated text file having rows like below and I want to create list from 6th column till last comma :-
FILE :-
*>,1.66.0.0/22,202.79.200.1,200,0,64515,4445,4445,64697,64697,64697,64697,i
*,14.0.184.0/24,202.79.200.64,200,0,64515,3491,9444,64574,?

Output Expected:-

List[1] = "64515,4445,4445,64697,64697,64697,64697"

List[2] = "64515,3491,9444,64574"

I have tried but it will return all values from first comma instead of starting from 6th comma and need to enclose those values using "" like mentioned above :-

for line in txtfile:
    line.split(',')

Answer (score 0):

NewLine variable holds how string split, then again joined

```
lst =[]
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        lst.append(','.join(line.split(',')[5:][:-1]))
    print(lst)
```

Note this is a simple split and join approach.

Answer (score 0):

You're best of using other libraries for this (csv or pandas for example), but if you want to do it without, you;d look at something like this:

```
data =[]
with open('file.ext', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(','.join(line.split(',')[5:-1]))
```